# .NET MVC - Return video file for jPlayer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, mp4

I have two methods and first one returns a video file, the other one returns thumbnail image.

```
  public ActionResult Video(string id)
    {
        UserVideo videoEntity = AccountBasicEntity.GetUserVideoWithID(id);

        string videoPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VideoPath"] + videoEntity.VideoFileName;


        return File(videoPath, "video/mp4");
    }

    public ActionResult Thumb(string id)
    {
        UserVideo videoEntity = AccountBasicEntity.GetUserVideoWithID(id);

        string thumbPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ThumbsPath"] + videoEntity.PreviewImageFileName;

        return File(thumbPath, "image/jpg");
    }
```

and I can reach the urls as

```
http://localhost/media/video/GTt-b2DcEG ( returns video file )
http://localhost/media/thumb/GTt-b2DcEG ( returns image file )
```

The method works fine which returns image file. But the other one doesn't work, browser (chrome) doesn't play or jPlayer doesn't play the video file But browser or jplayer shows the thumbnail image. I debugged and paths are ok.

Video path is : C:\Web\data\videos\GTt-b2DcEG.mp4
Image path is : C:\Web\data\thumbs\GTt-b2DcEG.jpg

Do I miss something ? what is the best way to feed a ajax-based video player in this situation?

Thanks.

Client side :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />

<!-- Website Design By: www.happyworm.com -->
<title>Demo : jPlayer as a video player</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "http://localhost/media/video/GTt-b2DcEG",
                poster: "http://localhost/media/thumb/GTt-b2DcEG"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v",
        size: {
            width: "640px",
            height: "360px",
            cssClass: "jp-video-360p"
        }
    });

});
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video jp-video-360p">
            <div class="jp-type-single">
                <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
                <div class="jp-gui">
                    <div class="jp-video-play">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-video-play-icon" tabindex="1">play</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-interface">
                        <div class="jp-progress">
                            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                                <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                        <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                        <div class="jp-title">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Big Buck Bunny Trailer</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="jp-controls-holder">
                            <ul class="jp-controls">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                            </div>

                            <ul class="jp-toggles">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-full-screen" tabindex="1" title="full screen">full screen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-restore-screen" tabindex="1" title="restore screen">restore screen</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-no-solution">
                    <span>Update Required</span>
                    To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to show how you are consuming the video on the client side.

Comment: I'm using jPlayer and set the video url as http://localhost/media/video/GTt-b2DcEG, if I set the video url as a file url ( http://localhost/sample.mp4 ) it works.

Comment: I meant code on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what troubleshooting you had already done.

When I've had this issue in the past, the first thing I check is that you have added the mime type in IIS. By default, IIS 6 & 7 won't serve up content for mime types that are not configured.

[How to add mime types with IIS7 Web.config](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx)

Next would be that the codec used to encode the mp4 is playable by the jPlayer.

[jPlayer Media Encoding](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-media-encoding)

Comment: I have already add MIME type for mp4 as (video/mp4). The problem is MVC doesn't return the mp4 video file, returns nothing when I use "return File(path,mimetype)".